# Ionic2 on production mode mess with the styles

Tags: ionic2, production-environment

I have been trying to compile a ionic2 iOS application and I have a big issue with the styles when I tried to go with the production process.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please add the errors or issues you have and explain what you already did to try to solve it.

Comment: I don't have errors.  Just when I build in production environment I lost half of the styles. In development I have no styles issues.

Comment: Try adding ViewEncapsulation.None